# Grease added to windshield wiper arm by shop

Tags: bolts, preventive-maintenance

A few months ago my fiance's cars windshield wiper wasn't working, I looked at it and the bolt was loose. I tightened it down and put loctite on it. It recently went into the dealership for an oil change and I just got the reminder to go check my work (make sure the bolt was still tight). I pulled the cap off that covers the bolt and there was a clear Vaseline like grease in there that I don't remember putting in there. I checked the other wiper and it had it too. Is that a normal thing to put on wiper bolts?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is it's dielectric grease to prevent corrosion. Also, was there rust in the pivot area? Sometimes you add grease there to improve the pivot ability